# Getting error like 'Error eacces mkdir' while run 'npm install -g create-react-app' command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm

When I try to install reactjs by `npm install -g create-react-app` command in Ubuntu I am getting an error as following. please help me remove these error.

giving me this error-

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/veomit10/tmp/npm-6710-iquektSI'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/veomit10/tmp/npm-6710-iquektSI']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/veomit10/tmp/npm-6710-iquektSI' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-144-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /home/veomit10/reactApp
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/veomit10/tmp/npm-6710-iquektSI
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/veomit10/tmp/npm-6710-iquektSI'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/veomit10/reactApp/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you please write how did you install it, which commands?

Comment: 'npm install -g create-react-app' i am using this command.

Comment: try to use sudo first, like sudo npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: ok thanks. now its working fine.

Comment: now it is giving me '/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory' when using  create-react-app hello-world.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to install it from a non-root user so in this case, you have to have the root permissions in order to install a global node modules.

just try to run commands from the root user, run this first
`sudo su`

after that run:
`npm install -g create-react-app`

if you still having error **'/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory'**

try to run this command `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` and re install creat-react-app again.

Comment: i updated the answer, you can try to run this `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` and after that `npm install -g create-react-app`